# NDSolve - 2nd order ODE - how to solve for y and y'

Tags: numerical-integration

i am trying to workout how to solve a simple 2nd order ODE for y and y'. I can solve for y[t] as follows but how can i solve for y[t] and y'[t] ?

```
m = 1; g = 9.82;
sol = Flatten @ 
   NDSolve[{y''[t] == -m g - 0.3 y'[t], y'[0] == 10, y[0] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[y[t] < 0, tmax = t; "StopIntegration"]}, 
    y[t], {t, 0, 3}];
Plot[y[t] /. sol, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

Also the output from NDSolve is an interpolating function but how do i turn this into a function ? i.e i thought it would be something like this but that doesn't seem to work ?

```
g[t_]:= y[t]/. sol
```

Thanks
David.

Answer (score 3):

To solve for $y(t)$ and $y'(t)$ you simply add $y'(t)$ for the list of the dependent functions you want to solve for.

```
m = 1; g = 9.82;

sol = Flatten@
   NDSolve[{y''[t] == -m g - 0.3 y'[t], y'[0] == 10, y[0] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[y[t] < 0, tmax = t; "StopIntegration"]}, {y[t],y'[t]}, {t, 0, 3}];

Plot[{y[t] /. sol, y'[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for the (new as of version 9) [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolveValue.html) function, which can return pretty complicated expressions based on the dependent variables in a system of numerically integrated differential equations. The following, for example, will plot both `y` and `y'`.

```
With[{value = 
   NDSolveValue[{y''[t] == -m g - 0.3 y'[t], y'[0] == 10, y[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[y[t] < 0, tmax = t; "StopIntegration"]}, {y[t], 
    y'[t]}, {t, 0, 3}]},
 Plot[value, {t, 0, tmax}]]
```

Of course, *Mathematica* knows how to take the derivatives of interpolating functions returned by ordinary `NDSolve`, so the following will also work fine:

```
With[{solution = 
   NDSolve[{y''[t] == -m g - 0.3 y'[t], y'[0] == 10, y[0] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[y[t] < 0, tmax = t; "StopIntegration"]}, y, {t, 0, 3}]},
 Plot[{y[t], y'[t]} /. solution // Evaluate, {t, 0, tmax}]]
```

Also, if you want to avoid the semi-gross `tmax = t` side-effect in your `WhenEvent` statement, you can use this quasi-documented feature to get the domain of an interpolating function:

```
With[{if = 
   y /. First@
     NDSolve[{y''[t] == -m g - 0.3 y'[t], y'[0] == 10, y[0] == 0, 
       WhenEvent[y[t] < 0, tmax = t; "StopIntegration"]}, 
      y, {t, 0, 3}]},
 if["Domain"]]
```

This returns `{{0., 1.86386}}` on my machine. Complex objects taking strings like `"Domain"` as arguments as a way of providing more complex "methods" is a pretty common pattern.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response. Very neat. I was trying to differentiate the interpolating function but had trouble turning the interpolation function into a function i could use.